# Views permission does not work

Tags: users

I have created a view by the name of news and there is an option under page setting by the name of access.

I have selected view any news content for the access option, then I have faced a problem. The problem is when I give any kind of view permission for news view, I cant access except give the permission of view any news content.

What do I have to do to give a permission of 'view own news content' so every person can see his/her news content?

Answer (score 1):

Create a relationship between the current content type, and users.

Select Content: Author and click on Add and configure relationships. Leave the settings as they are and click on Apply (all displays).

**Filtering the view**

Now you need to filter the view to display only content authored by the current user.

Use the filter **"User: Current".**